# Multiple filters handling different nested data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have two search inputs that handle filtering a table in AngularJS.

```
<input type="text" name="clientRefFilter" data-ng-model="filterPortfolio.clientRef">
<input type="text" name="appNoFilter" data-ng-model="filterPortfolio.ep_ApplicationNumber"">

<tr data-ng-repeat="patent in $ctrl.portfolioData | filter: filterPortfolio as Result">
   <td>
       <a data-ng-bind="patent.ep_ApplicationNumber"></a>
   </td>
   <td>
       <a data-ng-bind="patent.clientRef"></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I now need to add a drop-down filter that is populated by an array in the controller `filterTopLevelCat` that categorizes all the tables data, which comes from `patent.serviceList` which I then have to display alternative text to the user. Check below:

***controller***

```
vm.filterTopLevelCat = [ //drop-down filter options
  {name: 'All Patents'}, //no filter applied
  {name: 'Action Available'}, //Epct available and Epct being generated items shown
  {name: 'No Action Available'} // Epct rejected items shown
]
```

***view***

```
<input type="text" name="clientRefFilter" data-ng-model="filterPortfolio.clientRef">
<input type="text" name="appNoFilter" data-ng-model="filterPortfolio.ep_ApplicationNumber"">

<select data-ng-options="item.name for item in $ctrl.filterTopLevelCat">
</select>

<tr data-ng-repeat="patent in $ctrl.portfolioData | filter: filterPortfolio as Result">
 <td>
     <a data-ng-bind="patent.ep_ApplicationNumber"></a>
 </td>
 <td>
     <a data-ng-bind="patent.clientRef"></a>
 </td>
 <td>
   <table>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="item in patent.serviceList">
         <td>
            <span data-ng-if="item.serviceStatus == 'Epct available'">Ready for E-PCT</span>
            <span data-ng-if="item.serviceStatus == 'Epct rejected'">Not Eligble</span>
            <span data-ng-if="item.serviceStatus == 'Epct being generated'">Form 1200 generating</span>
         <td>
      <tr>
   <table>
<td>
```

I used an `ng-change` directive to access the filter from the controller, and go it to work with removing the filter but struggled to filter the data based on the status values. e.g. `Epct available`

***Question***

How should I approach this so a filter handles the filtering for the original two search inputs, and the new drop down filter?

Comment: have you tried using 'patent in $ctrl.portfolioData | filter: filterPortfolio' ? Not sure why you need as Result. The data structure should match what is in your ng-repeat. the children on filterPortfolio looks similar to that of patent in ng-repeat so 'filter: filterPortfolio' shoud be enough.

Comment: Apologies for some reason my select filter did not display. And the Result is for UI purposes which I didn't include so apologies about that too